# Как сделать реферальную систему для бота

Tags: c++

Как сделать реферальную систему для бота. так, чтоб при открытии бота чтобы начать его использовать необходимо было пригласить два человека в этого бота. +сделать вознаграждение за каждого реферала?

Comment: если я попадаю куда то где от меня требуется кого то привести, тут есть всего 2 варианта, что я делаю: 1. ухожу и больше не возвращаюсь. 2. если понимаю что мне все таки надо туда попасть я создаю двух мультов, которых приглашаю.

Comment: Что такое мульт?

Comment: подставной аккаунт, созданный тем же человеком, выдающим себя за другого человека